# Cassandra: Loading part of table's columns performance

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Lets consider these two tables...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lp_operations.campaign_changed (
  oe text,               // owner email                  
  ud timestamp,          // updated
  PRIMARY KEY((oe))
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lp_operations.campaign_data (
  oe text,              // owner email
  kp set<text>,         // each text in set is serialized object in JSON
  ud timestamp,         // updated
  PRIMARY KEY((oe))
);
```

If we assume that number of rows and contained "oe", "ud" values are identical. Are following two selects at same performance level for Cassandra?

```
Select select1 = select().all().from("lp_operations", "campaign_changed").where(eq("oe", email)).limit(1);
CampaignChanged obj1 = cas.selectOne(select1, CampaignChanged.class);

Select select2 = select().column("oe").column("ud").from("lp_operations", "campaign_data").where(eq("oe", email)).limit(1);
CampaignData obj2 = cas.selectOne(select2, CampaignData.class);
```

I want to know if second select isn't more complicated than first one. If there is not extra overhead. For example if whole rows (all columns) were loaded internally in cassandra and consequently desired columns were picked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The performance of the 2nd query could be slower than first, but it's really depends on several factors:

- number of entries in the `set` - it's not recommended to store more than hundreds of elements in the collection types;
- size of the text entries;
- are you storing the data in once, or you're periodically updating the entries in the set - in this case the data for same partition could reside in multiple SSTables that need to be read.

If you never do the partial updates of the data, then you can use `frozen<set<text>>` - in this case, all data of set will be stored together and read at once, avoiding searching in multiple SSTables (although it may search in all SSTables for other fields).

Also, please take into account that if you're continuously performs that query, then it's better not to use [SchemaBuilder](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/manual/statements/built/), like you shown, but better to [prepare query once and then bind variables into it for execution](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/manual/statements/prepared/) - in this case server won't re-parse CQL query on every request.